# How to discriminate the background and signal events in high energy physics (HEP) when they have a similar distribution on a variable?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, data-analysis

In high energy physics (HEP), the *Punzi method* is usually used to optimization cut to discriminate signals and background events in some typical distributions, like PID variable, when Signal and background have different distributions.

But if signal and background have same/similar distribution, how can we discriminate them using the variable cut?
The following two distributions show we can't discriminate them just using these two variable.

[image: The distribution of Signal and Background in variable A]
[image: The distribution of Signal and Background in variable B]

Comment: What concrete physical situation are you thinking about here where signal and noise would have the same distribution?

Comment: When I was still in the field that was considered an irreducible background. rfl has it right: you have to build a better experiment that can separates the two. If you can't... that's the end of the line.

Comment: Your first variable is probably not useful for background rejection (but you need to think _why_ is that the case? What is the origin of your background? Why does it have this distribution?). However, your second variable shows some separation power and can be used for background rejection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your observable signal and background distributions look the same in all observables, then you can not discriminate between the two, that should be obvious. So you could

- look at other parameters, hoping to find one where the distributions look different
- build a better experiment

In the case of your first figure,

- take more data and hope that there will be small differences that, with enough events, become statistically significant

In the case of your second figure,

- carefully calibrate your background distribution such that you can subtract it out. Remember to do proper error propagation.

I would

- do a combined fit of background+signal. Whatever you know about your background goes in the fit as constraints, and you can model shape uncertainties etc. too. Spend anything from an hour on GitHub to three entire PhD theses on that one problem. Then do a likelihood fit or a Bayesian fit to extract the amplitude of your signal. This way you don't need to cut at all, so you retain more of your signal in your final analysis, which is good. If done properly, this also gives you both the statistical and systematic uncertainties on the signal amplitude.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I don't intend to cut on these two variables anymore. Actually, these variables are usually used to reject background in this field. I have to try to explain why they have same distribution in my theses. Thank you again.